# How to setState in objects of arrays in the react state?

Tags: reactjs

How to change the values of a object in the array in the react state by using setState?

My react state:

```
this.state = {
    serviceFees: [
        {
        periodFrom: new Date(),
        periodTo: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
        serviceFeeType: 'percentage',
        serviceFee: '',
        refundableStatus: 'refundable'
        }
    ]
};
```

And some of my onChange fuctions:

```
handlePeriodFromDateChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
        periodFrom: date,
        periodTo: new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
    });
}

handleRefundableStatus = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        refundableStatus: e.target.value
    })
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are doing it wrong. You can't directly write the properties name and value, without telling which index you want to update.

If you want to update the object property of lets say first index of the array then you have to do in like :

```
handlePeriodFromDateChange = (date) => {
    consr 
    this.setState({
       serviceFees: this.state.serviceFees.map((e,i)=>{
          if(i === 0) {
            return {
              ...e, 
              periodFrom: date,
              periodTo: new Date(date.getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)
            }
          }
          return e;
       }})
    });
}
```

You have to change the reference of both the array and the object inside the array which you want to update. For changing the reference of the array you an use map method, which returns a new array.